# Can a PUT perform a merge on an entity without using a custom PUT operation?

Tags: rest, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I would like to implement a PUT request that merges data.
For example:

I have an entity `Article` where the `content` property is `"Lorem Ipsum. "` and when I perform a PUT on that entity with `content` = `"Hey !"` I would like to the end result to be `"Lorem Ipsum. Hey !"`.

Is that possible to do without a custom PUT operation?

Comment: Without a custom operation, is not possible.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks !

Comment: According to [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) `PUT` is defined to replace the current representation available for the given target URI with the payload provided in the request. However, the spec also states that the server should perform constraint checks beforehand which allows it to store syntactically different representations than provided within in the request payload. Though your request seems to target an append method. This is more suited for `PATCH` or `POST` operations though unless you want to send the whole `Lorem Ipsum. Hey !` content

Comment: Note further that if you misuse `PUT` for an append operation, you basically will miss out on its `idempotent` property as in case of a network failure you will end up with different results on resending the request depending on whether the previous request reached the server or not, hence I strongly recommend not to use PUT in such a case!

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not possible with a standard PUT, you can always write a wrapper to do it for you :)

````
public void PutWithConcatenation(string contentToConcatenate)
{
    // use GET request here
    string articleContent = GetArticle().content;
    string concatenatedContent = articleContent + contentToConcatenate;

    // use PUT request here
    UpdateArticle(concatenatedContent);
}

PutWithConcatenation("Hey!");

```
````

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to implement a PUT request that merges data.

Unfortunately, that's not what [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) means; so you have two problems -- first, because you aren't using the standard meaning for PUT, you are going to have to craft your own bespoke implementation.  Second, general purpose components aren't going to know about your hijacking of PUT semantics, so you are leaving yourself exposed -- any loss of property will be attributed to your violation of the semantics.

Much better to use PUT for PUT, and use something else (POST, [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)), when you want *merge*.

There is a registered [MERGE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3253#section-11.2) method;  is part of the WebDAV specification.  You could review that spec to see if the defined semantics are close to what you want.